# How to combine jquery codes with similar functions?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to lessen the code or recreate similar code with same function with this:    [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/willrpx/71eyg9gv/2/).Thanks

```
$(".addcolor:contains('red')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/(red)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>')
});
$(".addcolor:contains('blue')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/(blue)/g, '<span class="blue">$1</span>')
});
$(".addcolor:contains('green')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/(green)/g, '<span class="green">$1</span>')
});
```

The function of the code is to replace a specific text with span . How about to apply the css directly with the jquery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using an array for storing all the color values and creating regex:

```
var arr = ['red','green','blue'];

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
$(".addcolor").html(function(_, html) {

    var regex = new RegExp("("+arr[i]+")","g");
    htmla = '<span class="'+arr[i]+'">$1</span>';

   return  html.replace(regex, htmla);
});
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/71eyg9gv/10/

Comment: yet another good answer. I just really can't say which one is better.

Comment: You don't even need the `:contains` in the selector, you can just remove it.

Comment: @DarkAshelin thanks for correcting, i started with the original code , so i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not the best at Javascript regex stuff, here's my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/71eyg9gv/4/

Basically I made your repeating sections a function and then declared it with the variables.

```
function addColor(object) {
    $(".addcolor:contains(" + object +")").html(function(_, html) {
        var re = new RegExp(object,"g");
        return  html.replace(re, '<span class="' + object +'">' + object + '</span>')
    });
}

addColor('red');
addColor('blue');
addColor('green');
```

Comment: Thanks sir, that one is a lot better I think. Is it possible to include the css on the jquery code? Instead of wrapping it, just directly apply a color.

Comment: If they were wrapped in something beforehand, you could directly apply the color. Since they're part of a string, it's not possible to target them with a direct style

Comment: Indeed as @austinthedeveloper has said, you can only style elements (with jQuery), not strings.